# TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation while reading last object from model

Tags: python, django

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

```
class DownloadPDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        patientInfo.objects.all()
        # data.update({'Pregencies':pInfo.Pregencies,'Glucose':Glucose,'BloodPressure':BloodPressure,'SkinThickness':SkinThickness,'Insulin':Insulin,'BMI':BMI,'DiabetesPedigreeFunction':DiabetesPedigreeFunction,'Age':Age,'username':request.user,'result':predict})
        pdf = render_to_pdf('accounts/pdf_template.html', data)
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
        content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
```

Comment: The line `patientInfo.objects.all()` is indented with spaces but all other lines are indented with tabs. You cannot mix the two in Python

Comment: It helps if you include more of the error. I am not sure how @Iain Shelvington identified the line with the problem, but the error will indicate the line with the problem.

Comment: @Vincent if you go to edit the question you get the raw pasted code, the tab/space issue can be found there

Comment: @IainShelvington I just figured out I miss-read your answer, I was looking for tabs on that line, and only finding spaces, the tabs are what the other lines have.